# register-login user jquery > ashx > c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, security, authentication, forms-authentication

before now i usually use asp.net login and register control to manage users.

but now i want to write a client side login with diffrent view, so just like other information i decided to collect user name and password, make a json string, and pass to ashx handler, but now i am not sure it is safe to send password in this way:

```
var pass = $('#psw').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "login.ashx",
        data: { "password": pass },
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error:{
        }
        });
```

my question is: what is best solution?
is there a complete tutorial in c#, vb and jquery?

Comment: in this case, you can use the ASP.NET AJAX (the one built in visual studio) too! :)

Comment: any tutorial? isn't ajax safe?

Comment: ajax is safe. since you are using asp.net you have two AJAX options: 1) jQuery AJAX 2) ASP.NET AJAX .. you can use both, both are great, you can switch from one to the other if you face any prob :)

Comment: i saw ajax in jquery has password option? can i use it? how to retrieve in ashx?

Answer (score 1):

If your application will be using https protocol then it's safe to send password this way. If not password will be sent in plain text. Meaning it's not a safe solution. Someone could track your HTTP traffic and intercept your password as it's sent in plain text.

Same problem exist by using asp.net login and register controls, though.

Here a tutorial on how to enable SSL (https support) in IIS 7.0 for development enviroment using self-signed certificate.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx

Regards,

Uroš

Comment: thank you, would you direct me about https protocol. any tutorial? send password as plain text is secure?

Comment: Hi, I revised my answer to include answers to questions in your comment.

Comment: thank you but i think must be simpler but safe, i saw some tutorial serialize form! thank you any way.